# using $this or parent:: to call inherited methods?

Tags: php

Not really a problem, more like curiosity on my part but as an example, say I have a php class:

```
class baseTestMain
{
    protected function testFunction()
    {
        echo 'baseTestMain says hi';
    }
}
```

and another class that extends from that class above:

```
class aSubClass extends baseTestMain
{
    public function doingSomething()
    {
        parent::testFunction();
        //someextrastuffhere
    }
}
```

Normally, when I want to call a parent method when defining a new method in the subclass I would do the above - `parent::methodnamehere()` however instead of `parent::` you can also use `$this->methodname()` and the operation would be the same.

```
class aSubClass extends baseTestMain
{
    public function doingSomething()
    {
        $this->testFunction();
        //someextrastuffhere
    }
}
```

So what I'm asking is, should I use `parent::testFunction();` or use `$this->testFunction();` ? or is there a difference to it that I've missed? If not, whats your preference or the preferred method?

Do note that I am not overriding or extending that function in the subclass, essentially the implementation is carried over from the parent.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In your case, since `aSubClass::testFunction()` is inherited from `baseTestMain::testFunction()`, use `$this->testFunction()`. You should only use `parent::testFunction()` if you're going to override that method in your subclass, within its implementation.

The difference is that `parent::` calls the parent's implementation while `$this->` calls the child's implementation *if the child has its own implementation instead of inheriting it from the parent*.

Comment: "Do note that I am not overriding or extending that function in the subclass, essentially the implementation is carried over from the parent."

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: Thanks, I added another paragraph to the top that answers the question. I guess my example is irrelevant so I scrapped it.

Comment: @Aesphere, Considering readability and concept, this is the best answer.

Answer (score 7):

Calling the method on the parent prevents the class's children from participating in polymorphism properly since their redefinition of the method will never be called.