# Call to a member function Check() on a non-object

Tags: php, class, function

i have a problem with php class, I would bring return=true or false from a function of a class to another function of another class

```
<?php

class CheckCity {

    private $x = 10;
    private $y = 10;

    public function __construct () {

        $this->x = rand(10, 10);
        $this->y = rand(10, 10);

    }

    public function Check() {

        $exists =  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM _users WHERE x = $this->x AND y = $this->y LIMIT 1");

        if ( mysql_num_rows ( $exists ) == 1 ) {

            return true;

        } else {

            return false;

        }

    }

}

class setCity extends CheckCity {

    public function Set() {
        parent::Check();
        if ( $setcity->Check() == true ) {

            echo "is TRUE";

        } else {

            echo "is FALSE";

        }

    }

}
```

And this is the index:

```
<?php

$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die ('Error 1.');
mysql_select_db('db', $conn) or die ('Error 2.');

include "func.php";

$checkcity = new CheckCity();
$checkcity->Check();

$setcity = new setCity();
$setcity->Set();
```

So this is the Error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function Check() on a non-object in /func.php on line 37
```

I searched the error to google and I tried many solutions but to no avail.

Comment: It's good practice to start class names with an uppercase letter and member functions and other variable names with lowercase letters.

Comment: I believe when you are extending the class, you are casting `parent::Check();` as static method, hence you are not able to instantiate it, in an object context.

Comment: "Error...on line 37" which one is line 37?

Comment: @Simon_eQ `parent::Check()` only gets called as static if the caller context is static; it works as expected here.

Comment: If you tried many solutions, it helps to mention at least a few here.

Answer (score 2):

Your code:

```
$setcity->Check()
```

should be:

```
$this->Check()
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is here:

```
 if ( $setcity->Check() == true ) {
```

$setcity is not declared as being a new instance of SetCity class.

```
class setCity extends CheckCity {

    public function Set() {
        if ( $this->Check() ) {

            echo "is TRUE";

        } else {

            echo "is FALSE";

        }

    }

}
```

See [using $this or parent:: to call inherited methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101945/using-this-or-parent-to-call-inherited-methods)

It's not strictly necessary to do $this, but I recommend you to do it in case you override the method in your class (the one that is extending).

Answer (score 0):

In your setCity class, you are referencing an undeclared variable `$setcity` and attempting to call a function on it. As there's no class in `$setcity`, php raises fatal error.

If you want to operate on a current object within that object's methods, use the `$this` keyword.

PS. You should really read some programming best practices about naming your classes and their methods... :)