# Would I use self, static, this in a Controller

Tags: php, laravel

I extends one of my controller from another one like this:

> class ProductController extends APIProductController

then, now I would use one APIProductController 's function which it name is ShowUser in ProductController

```
<-------1------->
public function ShowUser()
{
    return $this->ShowUser();
}

<-------2------->
public function ShowUser()
{
    return static::ShowUser();
}

<-------3------->
public function ShowUser()
{
    return self::ShowUser();
}
```

Comment: Maybe answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101945/using-this-or-parent-to-call-inherited-methods#answer-5101982).

Answer (score 3):

You will need to use `parent` keyword, in order to call the Base class's function in the Child class:

```
public function ShowUser()
{
    return parent::ShowUser();
}
```

From [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php):

> Example #3 Calling a parent's method
>
> ```
> class MyClass
> {
>     protected function myFunc() {
>         echo "MyClass::myFunc()\n";
>     }
> }
>
> class OtherClass extends MyClass
> {
>     // Override parent's definition
>     public function myFunc()
>     {
>         // But still call the parent function
>         parent::myFunc();
>         echo "OtherClass::myFunc()\n";
>     }
> }
> ```